# TCP Socket connection not working on Android 4.4

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

Faced a weird problem when TCP connection via Socket is not established on Android 4.4 for some reason. It works fine on 4.1.1 and 5.0.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Creating InetAddress object from ipNumber passed via constructor from IpGetter class.
            InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host); 

            // Create a new Socket instance and connect to host
            socket = new Socket(serverAddress, port);
            Log.i(TAG, "Socket created: " + host + ":" + port);

            // Create PrintWriter object for sending messages to server.
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true); //thread freezes here

            //Create BufferedReader object for receiving messages from server.
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            Log.d(TAG, "In/Out created");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Don't know about host: " + host + ":" + port);
            connected = false;
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + host + ":" + port);
            connected = false;
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        connected = true;
        return null;
    }
```

For some reason Thread stops on I/O creation.

Any ideas what causes this? Maybe someone seen that problem before?

Comment: Do you test this on different devices? Are they connected on the same network, i.e. do they have working internet connection?

Comment: Yes, I've been testing it on 3 physical mobile devices. They were in the same WiFi network with access to Internet. Unfortuantely I don't have the possibility to test on another 4.4 device. Perhabs problem within phone but I don't really belive so. The device is Huawei Accent p6

Comment: Btw what is the exact message that IOException carries?

Comment: And that's the funniest thing - no exceptions. Thread simply freezes there

Comment: Then maybe you can first try if it is bound and connected, before getting the output stream?

Comment: what do you mean by that? this log triggers `Log.i(TAG, "Socket created: " + host + ":" + port);` And the next one does not.

Comment: My idea is to check the result of `socket.isBound()` and `socket.isConnected()`

Comment: added this `if (socket.isBound() && socket.isConnected()) {...} else {...}`. And yea.. still the same. I put Logs inside `if() { Log.d } else { Log.e }`. And noone triggers. Kind a magic

Comment: Would you like to continue this discussion in a chat room? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81531/tcp-socket-connection-not-working-on-android-4-4

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Seems like connection works even with that weird behaviour. Messages are sent via socket and received properly. But still no idea why thread stopped respond after creating socket..